# Как сделать цену товара зависимой от его количества в интернет магазине на Битрикс?

Tags: битрикс, 1с, интернет-магазин

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы от количества товара, которое желает приобрести пользователь, зависела его цена. Например, цена за 1 - 10 штук - 200, за 11-20 штук - на 4% меньше (то есть 200 * 0,96), за 21 - 30 - еще на 4% меньше (то есть 200 * 0,96 * 0,96) и т.д. Причем для разных категорий товаров разный процент. Я не специалист по битрикс, работаю с ним совсем не давно, но выполнить эту задачу нужно обязательно. Пробовала разные способы, ничего не получается, цена не меняется. Буду очень благодарна за помощь!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю есть 2 легальных способа

1. В самом товаре - Торговый каталог
   можно установить тип цены для определенного количества.
   при этом нужно сделать вид цен с наценкой, или скидкой.
   учет +40%. Учет +38% и подставить на какое количество они действуют.
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второй вариант это через маркетинг, там более гибкая наценка в разрезе групп.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]